# JSP - redirect or rewrite with parameters ( POST )

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, redirect

we already shared a URL to other systems and they are sending post request with 3 parameters that we already agreed.

But now we have to change it, so I don't want to tell them anything about this change

I need to find a way to redirect the post request from the old JSP page to a new one

or maybe from the old JSP page it self sending new request with the 3 parameters that I already know

I don't want to use javascript for this, I need it to be done in JSP

hope that you can help me with this :-)

Comment: As a note, you should not be using JSP for business logic.  It is View part of MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<jsp:forward page="relativeURL | <%= expression %>">  
<jsp:param name="parametername" value="parametervalue | <%=expression%>" />  
</jsp:forward>
```

This should help you. For more details:
https://www.javatpoint.com/jsp-action-tags-forward-action

Comment: thanks, but I know the parameter name, but I don't know the value of it.

Comment: <%=request.getParameter("paramName")%> is the way of getting param value

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked fine with me, do you know if there is there any negative things about this solution ?